# How can I override Bootstrap's navs.less CSS definitions?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My page looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-caret">
    <li class="active">
      <a class="nav-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#app">Item 1</a> </li>
    <li>..</li>
    ...
```

I want the active `li` to be a different color than the default which comes from this when doing inspect in browser:

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus, .nav-
  pills>li.active>a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

I tried putting it in two ways as:

```
 .nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus, .nav-
    pills>li.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}

.nav-pills.navbar-toggle >li:active{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #36758D;
}
```

in my own navbar.transparent.css file but nothing changes.

Comment: It might help adding !important after the color, such as: background-color: #337ab7 !important;

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #36758D;
}
```

If you use exactly the same selectors that are in Bootstrap's stylesheet, it should just work, because the CSS specificity is the same, and your rules win because they come after Bootstrap's (assuming you're importing your own stylesheet after Bootstrap, which you should be doing anyway).

Also note that `:active` works only when you actually click on the link; is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: I tried it exactly as above, no change in color and also tried it with the !important after the background color, no change either.   Maybe I should list my include statements.  So I have a head.inc.php that is included in every page.  Here's it's order of includes:

Comment: function addHead() {...
  echo css_link('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
  echo css_link('/assets/styles/navbar.transparent.css');
  echo css_link('/assets/styles/navbar.mobileSize.css');
  echo css_link(' /body.container.css');
  echo css_link(' /footer.css');
  echo css_link(' /styles.css');
  echo css_link('/header.navbar.css');
  echo css_link('/assets/styles/searchbar.css');
  echo js_link('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js');
  echo js_link('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js');
...

Comment: Have you checked if the stylesheets are being included in the rendered page? e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` — another quick test could be to add `body { background: red }` to the CSS and if the page turns red it works

Comment: When I expand my header section under debug tools, I see my link.

Comment: actually, it does change color for as long as my mouse click is not released.  once released it changes back to the standard color.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how `:active` works. My guess is you want to style `.active` instead?